# Any idea how can i send message in whatsapp in background

Tags: android, message, whatsapp

I am new in Android, I want to send a message on whats up from my application without open the whats up UI. is it possible..

please suggest me..

On stack overflow there are many questions similar to this. But there is no proper answer.

Comment: As of May 2015, [WhatsApp has no API nor any plans for such an API](http://mashable.com/2015/03/25/whatsapp-developers-api/). I suggest that you move on to some other project.

Comment: public void sendMessage(View v) {

  String whatsAppMessage = message.getText().toString();

  Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
  sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, whatsAppMessage);
  sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

  // Do not forget to add this to open whatsApp App specifically
  sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
  startActivity(sendIntent);

 }   I have used this piece of code. But this is not able to full fill my requirement.